# Where does PIL.Image.open() search for image when only the filename is given?

Tags: python, directory, python-imaging-library

I need to make a variation of chess game where people can download it on python but i need images now.
(Also something very surprising is that the directory shown in File Explorer is sometimes different than the directory in pycharm)

I tried putting them beside venv but it didn't work. I also tried in Scripts but i didn't work either.

Comment: It looks in the current working directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks in the current directory. You can see where that is by running this:

```
import os
print(f'Current directory: {os.getcwd()}')
```